# roundoff value to decimal 2 place with floor value

Tags: xquery, rounding

I am looking for help from XQuery experts where I need to round off values of a variable to 2 decimal places along with floor value like below.

say I am getting a variable value like 750.006 - value should be upto 2 decimal place. I am able to achieve that with help of below query.

```
fn-bea:format-number((xs:decimal($InputValue)),'0.00')
```

Now the issue is, I would like to have 3rd decimal digit to a floor value like say if

- if the value is coming as 750.006 , it should be rounded to 750.01  (upto 2 decimal place)
- if value is like 750.004 , it should be 750.00

could someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`fn-bea:decimal-round($value, $scale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13167_01/aldsp/docs25/xquery/extensions.html#wp1292749) to round the value before formatting it:

```
fn-bea:format-number(fn-bea:decimal-round(xs:decimal($InputValue), 2),'0.00')
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer?